# Show a set with sequences is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show the following set is countable:
$$A = \left\{\langle x_k \rangle _{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \in \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{Z}} \ \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \ (\lvert k \rvert > n \implies x_k = 0) \right\}$$

First of all, my intuition is that the set is comprised of infinite sequences of the form:

$$\{\dots, 0,0,1,2,-3,0,0, \dots \}$$
where the "inner" terms are arbitrary integers and the "outer" terms are zeros, $n$ being the index of the middle "inner" term and $\lvert k \rvert$ the distance from the middle term to zeros.

The classic approach is to show that there is an injective function $f: A \to \mathbb{N}$. My idea here is that we could take only the "inner" terms, treat them as finite sequences and come up with an injection $f:A \to \langle x_{n-k-1}, \dots, x_{n+k+1} \rangle$. I can't find such and injection, though. Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right that $A$ is the set of bi-infinite sequence (of integers) with finite support. The simplest way to convert $\sigma=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z\rangle$ to a finite sequence, assuming that it’s not the zero bi-infinite sequence, is to let $a_0=\min\{k\in\Bbb Z:x_k\ne 0\}$, $m=\max\{k\in\Bbb Z:x_k\ne 0\}$, and set

$$\langle a_1,\ldots,a_{m-a_0+1}\rangle=\langle x_{a_0},\ldots,x_m\rangle\;.$$

You can send the zero sequence to anything that doesn’t conflict with this; $\langle 0\rangle$ is one natural choice. The point of $a_0$ is that you need to be able to distinguish the sequences that differ only in the starting point of their non-zero part.